# Hide path in listBox and open object

Tags: c#, import, path, listbox

I have a listbox with a list of excel objects located in a folder, which itself is located next to the .exe file.

The listBox should present the objects with their filename only. However, this is where my issue comes in.

Because when you double-click the filename the data should open up in a datagrid next to the listbox. The problem is, when I present the objects in the list with filename only, my data import function can't locate the file because the sub-folder is hidden and is not present when I'm sending the path to my import function.

To illustrate, using the full path name in the listBox it looks like this:
`"Template/filename.xlsx"`
That way my import function can find the file.
But I want my listBox to only show the filename: `"Filename.xlsx"` but still be able to provide my import function with the full path like this: `"Template/filename.xlsx"`

Note that it does work when I'm not hiding the sub-folder path text in the listBox.

```
public void test_loadListBox()
    {
        /// Loads the listBox with the items in the template folder

        //Clear list at the start
        listBox.Items.Clear();

        // Location of the template files
        string path = "Templates";

        //find and add files from the directory
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        foreach(string file in files)
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(file); // Shows folder as well
            //listBox.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)); // shows only filename
        }
    }

public void LoadExcelTemplate(string locationString)
    {
        /// Import excel data to the datagrid.

        String sheetname = "Blad1";
        String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                        locationString +
                        ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"; ";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + sheetname + "$]", con);

        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(data);
        dataGrid.DataSource = data;
    }


private void listBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /// Double clicking an object in the list

        if (listBox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(listBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("DEBUG: " + Path.GetFullPath(listBox.SelectedItem.ToString()));
            LoadExcelTemplate(listBox.SelectedItem.ToString()); 

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your path variable a constant:

```
// Location of the template files
private const string TEMPLATE_FOLDER ="Templates";

public void test_loadListBox()
{
    /// Loads the listBox with the items in the template folder

    //Clear list at the start
    listBox.Items.Clear();

    //find and add files from the directory
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(TEMPLATE_FOLDER);
    foreach(string file in files)
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(file); // Shows folder as well
        //listBox.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)); // shows only filename
    }
}

public void LoadExcelTemplate(string locationString)
{
    /// Import excel data to the datagrid.

    String sheetname = "Blad1";
    String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                    locationString +
                    ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"; ";

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + sheetname + "$]", con);

    OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(data);
    dataGrid.DataSource = data;
}


private void listBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /// Double clicking an object in the list

    if (listBox.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(listBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG: " + System.IO.Path.Combine(TEMPLATE_FOLDER ,listBox.SelectedItem.ToString()));
        LoadExcelTemplate(System.IO.Path.Combine(TEMPLATE_FOLDER ,listBox.SelectedItem.ToString())); 

    }
}
```

Comment: I get an OleDbException when I try this, saying "database or object is read-only". Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @VinnieNovido Are your xlsx-files marked as readonly? Or is another process using them (like excel)? Or are you using the files in another part of your code?

Comment: Using the connection string "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Data Source=" + locationString + ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"; "; might help too (It opens the file for read-only).

Comment: I found a way to solve it. In the connection string, I added "IMEX=1" like this: "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                            locationString + 
                            ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"; ";
This enforces the ImportMixedTypes=Text registry setting.

Tried your solution as well and it also worked! Thanks!